# Filterrific, scope without argument and check boxes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, filterrific

I'm getting in filterrific, and find it really good for its integration with draper decorators and so.

But I would like to make a simple request with a scope without parameter.

Imagine a model scope like `scope :unassigned, -> { where(support_user: nil)}`. Then you can do `Ticket.unassigned` to perform the query.

How do I integrate this unparametred scope with filterrific? With an "unassigned" check box for example.

EDIT:
The form code:

```
<%= form_for_filterrific @filterrific do |f| %>
<%= f.hidden_field( :at_and_under_node_id,class: 'filterrific-periodically-observed') %>
<%= f.label "unassigned" %>
<%= f.check_box :unassigned, class: 'filterrific-periodically-observed' %>
<%= link_to('Reset filters',reset_filterrific_url) %>
 </div>
 <%# add an automated spinner to your form when the list is refreshed %>
 <%= render_filterrific_spinner %>
<% end %>
```

UPDATE:
Another feature that we miss is filter with enums. If I have

```
class Ticket < ActiveRecord::Base

 enum status: [:wait, :closed, :deleted]
 ...
end
```

And want to make a filter that call `Ticket.wait`, how would it be possible?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you post your form code?

Comment: Try `<%= f.check_box "filterrific[unassigned]", class: 'filterrific-periodically-observed' %>`

Comment: I get `undefined method 'filterrific[unassigned]' for #<Filterrific::ParamSet:0x007fa9c2b986d8>`

Comment: Looks like i'm not the only one to expect this function:https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/meta_search/issues/19 , http://osdir.com/ml/lang-ruby-rails-core/2011-06/msg00128.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've adapted filterrific in a way it can afford scope with arity 0 and enum requests. As arity doesn't reveal correctly the number of necessary arguments I use ArgumentError exception.
Hello! I had the same expect for fiterrific. I've made a fork. As arity for scope and enums doesn't work as expected I use the ArgumentError exception.

```
filterrific_available_filters.each do |filter_name|
    filter_param = filterrific_param_set.send(filter_name)
      next if filter_param.blank? # skip blank filter_params
      begin
        ar_rel = ar_rel.send(filter_name, filter_param)
      rescue ArgumentError #if we have a scope with arity 0 or enum query, we can perform the request without the parameter
        ar_rel = ar_rel.send(filter_name) if (filter_param == 1)
      end
    end
    ar_rel
end
```

Fork available here:
https://github.com/hachpai/filterrific

Answer (score 2):

Use a checkbox like so:

```
<%= f.check_box "unassigned", class: 'filterrific-periodically-observed' %>
```

Make sure that the `unassigned` scope exists and is added to the `filterrific` directive in your model.

Then pass the argument to your scope and check for the value:

```
scope :unassigned, ->(yes_or_no) {
  return nil  if '0' == yes_or_no
  where(support_user: nil)
}
```

Comment: Yeah I do like that now. But it annoy me to not be able to use a scope without argument

Comment: And anyway, I would like to make filter with enum in my model. I've updated my question to illustrate what I want. It seems to be impossible with filterrific